# lldb cannot evaluate function because of unknown identifier

Tags: c++, llvm, lldb

I have an optimized binary that has c++ structures and classes for which I was able to export the symbol of and set breakpoints for class functions, however, I cannot seem to do something basic like this: `expr ((ns::SomeClass*)$r0)->toString()`
lldb reports unknown identifier for ns.

From some google searching I found something about expr prefix files and attempted to write a header that describes the namespace but I still get the same error. Perhaps I am doing it wrong or there is another feature of lldb that would allow for this?

My prefix file was pretty simple, I just wanted to see if I could get past the unknown identifier bit and onto the error applied to SomeClass.

prefix.mm

```
namespace ns { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of thing it might be easier to just call this using the mangled name and passing the "this" pointer directly, i.e.:

```
(lldb) expr (const char *) _ZN2ns9SomeClass8toStringEv($r0)
```

Otherwise, you'll have to put a hollowed out version of the class and its method in your prefix file, i.e.:

```
 > cat prefix.h 
   namespace ns
   {
       class SomeClass
       {
       public:
           const char *toString();
       };
   }
```

that will allow you to do:

```
(lldb) expr ((ns::SomeClass *)$rdi)->toString()
```

Comment: I was able to get this working, thanks! My attempt before was rather close however I had a few other things in my prefix file that was rendering lldb unable to utilize it. I completely for I could use the name mangle directly, thanks for that tip!